# Xcode Apple Mach-0 Linker (Id) Error

Tags: c++, xcode4.6

I have looked at many of the other questions that are similar, and I can't figure out these errors.

"Fighter::takeDamage(int)", referenced from:

```
  vtable for Fighter in Fighter-D8AE20C4CA0F2F89.o
  vtable for Archer in Archer-2F4D431E1CB47450.o
  vtable for Cleric in Cleric-1332D02E7E206D4D.o
```

"Fighter::useAbility()", referenced from:

```
  vtable for Fighter in Fighter-D8AE20C4CA0F2F89.o
```

"Fighter::reset()", referenced from:

```
  vtable for Fighter in Fighter-D8AE20C4CA0F2F89.o
```

"Fighter::getDamage()", referenced from:

```
  vtable for Fighter in Fighter-D8AE20C4CA0F2F89.o
```

"Fighter::Fighter(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, int, int, int, int)", referenced from:

```
  Robot::Robot(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, int) in Robot-D3F84EA62D808B55.o
  Archer::Archer(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, int) in Archer-2F4D431E1CB47450.o
  Cleric::Cleric(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, int) in Cleric-1332D02E7E206D4D.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You might be mixing C++ libraries; check that all code uses `libc++`, unless you want to run it pre-10.7, in which case all code should use `libstdc++`.  Either way it should be consistent.

Comment: ok, that got rid of most of the erros. Now it's just the error "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: It says framework not found CPlusTest

Comment: And do *you* think that means?